# Does removeCallbacksAndMessages serialize?

Tags: android, handler

For purposes of example, suppose I have two methods that will be called asynchronously, doDelayEventA and doEventB. To simplify things we will assume that doDelayEventA will be called once and doEventB will be called once.

doDelayEventA starts a timer (actually a Handler) and doEventB kills it (if it is still pending).

```
    private Handler mTimer;

    public void doDelayEventA(){
        mTimer = new Handler();
        mTimer.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Event A: We want this to happen FIRST or not at all");
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    public void doEventB(){
        if (mTimer != null) {
            mTimer.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        }
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Event B: If it happens, it should ALWAYS happen LAST");
    }
```

The question: Does the removeCallbacksAndMessages force a serialization, that is, does it block execution until the runnable has been removed or executed? I would like to insure that given both methods are called, The EventA Log statement will always execute first or not at all ahead of the EventB Log statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the removeCallbacksAndMessages force a serialization, that is, does it block execution until the runnable has been removed or executed?

If `doEventB()` is executed on the main application thread (or, more accurately, on the same thread that the `Handler` is tied to), you should be in OK shape. `Handler` uses a `MessageQueue` for this, and `MessageQueue` does remove the message synchronously, at least in [Android 7.1](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-cts-7.1_r5/core/java/android/os/MessageQueue.java#L689-L720).

However:

- This is not documented behavior AFAIK, so there's some risk that other versions of Android behave differently
- If you call `doEventB()` on a different thread, while there should be no thread synchronization issues (e.g., `ConcurrentModificationException`), you may get a race condition: `doEventB()` is called on one thread, the `Runnable` starts executing on another thread, and the `doEventB()` log message happens before the `Runnable` log message